# Find serial number with one character difference

Tags: mysql

We have a list of devices with serial numbers, human error has occurred and we have noticed some of them have 1 incorrect character. To find potential matches I've got this query:

```
Looking for serial 1234

SELECT * FROM tblDevices 
WHERE serialNumber LIKE "123_"
OR serialNumber LIKE "12_4"
OR serialNumber LIKE "1_34"
OR serialNumber LIKE "_234"
```

This works and I can use PHP to incorporate all serial numbers, but this could become a lengthy query with some of the serial numbers containing 40 characters.

It also doesn't resolve if a user enters 2 characters wrong, but at least this narrows it down

I was wondering if there was a neater solution?

Thanks

**EDIT**

My php solution:

```
$serial = '123456789101112';

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblDevices WHERE ";

for($i=1; $i<=strlen($serial); $i++){
    if ($i > 1){
        $query .= " OR ";
    }
    $query .=  "serialNumber LIKE '" . substr_replace($serial, "_", -$i, 1) . "'";
}
```

Gives me a the query but it's quite lengthy:

```
SELECT * FROM tblDevices 
WHERE serialNumber LIKE '12345678910111_' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '1234567891011_2' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '123456789101_12' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '12345678910_112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '1234567891_1112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '123456789_01112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '12345678_101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '1234567_9101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '123456_89101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '12345_789101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '1234_6789101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '123_56789101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '12_456789101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '1_3456789101112' 
OR serialNumber LIKE '_23456789101112'
```

Comment: How many numbers do you have in practice? Letting people guess "close enough" is how you make life easier for people just taking a wild stab.

Comment: Rows of devices is about 2000. Varying length of serial number is 12-40 characters containing alphanumeric and hyphens.

Comment: Is 1235 a candidate when searching for 1234? and is 1223? and is 1134?

Comment: 1235: yes, 1223: No (2 characters incorrect), 1134: yes

Comment: So a rule would be if n-1 of n (where n = string length) characters in a string have the same value in the same position then item is a candidate? Not something I would like to do in sql - do you have any other options (python,php fortran..)

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, exactly. PHP is an option. would you grab all the data and then do the string comparison?

Comment: Sort of I would examine very character in the string

Comment: So I have a php solution, but wondered if there was something in mySQL that I was missing. I'll add my solution to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ you can use a recursive CTE to generate the patterns and then join on them.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
n
AS
(
SELECT '1234' n
),
p
AS
(
SELECT n.n n,
       0 l,
       char_length(n.n) - 1 r,
       concat('_', right(n.n, char_length(n.n) - 1)) p
       FROM n
UNION ALL
SELECT p.n,
       p.l + 1 l,
       p.r - 1 r,
       concat(left(p.n, p.l + 1), '_', right(p.n, p.r - 1)) p
       FROM p
       WHERE p.r - 1 >= 0
)
SELECT p.p,
       d.*
       FROM tbldevices d
            INNER JOIN p
                       ON d.serialnumber LIKE p.p;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b50bbd5f4416d7cb40ca0651f43150c8)

Comment: Those are some impressive SQL skills. Many thanks